# Tab indenting looks weird in gedit in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 18.04, 20.04, gedit

I have been working in a collaborative project with version control via GitHub. As much as we try to set standards for indentation, one problem still persists.

We use tabs (real tabs, not spaces) for indentation. A simple example of this problem happening is this: I edit a file in Gedit in a computer running Ubuntu 18.04, tab width set to 8, and then I push it to GitHub. The indentation looks good both in the computer that pushed it and in the GitHub browser visualization, but in a computer running Ubuntu 20.04 Gedit shows it differently, despite the same Tab Width setting of 8.

Code appearance in Ubuntu 18.04:

[image: Code appearance in Ubuntu 18.04]

Code appearance in the browser:

[image: Code appearance in the browser]

Code appearance in Ubuntu 20.04:

[image: Code appearance in Ubuntu 20.04]

I noticed the problem happens when the text before an indentation is in the limit of Tab Size. In the example of the pictures, after the text " fused_odometry" (with a space at the start), which has 15 characters, the tab in both Ubuntu 18.04 and GitHub adds only one space visually, to make up for the final character to be a multiple of 8. To me that sounds like the right way to do it.

In Ubuntu 20.04, the tab advances 8 spaces, and the second tab advances 7 more, making it a whole tab width ahead of the other editors.

I searched for things that could cause this difference, but I didn't find any mention of something other than tab width settings causing tabs to appear differently across editors.

As requested, adding the results of `gedit --version` from both computers.

Ubuntu 18.04:

```
gedit - Version 3.28.1
```

Ubuntu 20.04:

```
gedit - Version 3.36.2
```

[Link](https://github.com/LCAD-UFES/carmen_lcad/blob/master/bin/process-volta_da_ufes-pid_sensorbox.ini) to a file in which the problem appears in my Ubuntu 20.04 computer.

Comment: Perhaps you could post the `gedit --version` from both computers?

Comment: would you post `github` link? I can test it.

Comment: @Frankie0p Alright, edited it in

Comment: These kind of problems are sometimes related to faulty fonts. Can you try to change the `gedit`'s font to some other "monospace" font and/or change the font size? Please try "Courier New" 10.

Comment: @kenn Done. The file from the pictures is in a private repository, but I linked an equivalent one. I made sure the problem happens in it too

Comment: @FedKad "Courier New" wasn't available, but I changed it to "Liberation Mono Regular" 10 and yeah, that solved it! I was using the default one (Ubuntu Mono 13). But the problem shows even with "Liberation Mono Regular" if I change it to a bigger size. Is there a font immune to this? Using these crazy ones sounds like a nightmare now

Comment: Is your problem related to font spacing? Or is it a font rendering issue? Maybe user fault? Uncheck `preferences>view>text wrapping` .

Comment: @FedKad, I think I should settle with your solution. Should you post it as an answer for me to mark it solved? I'm new to this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the past I had similar problems with other applications. I think that these kind of problems are sometimes related to faulty fonts.

You can try to change `gedit`'s font to some other "monospace" font and/or change the font size.

I prefer "Courier New" 10pt which seems to have less problems.